# Sinatra API Versioning

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra

I'm new to APIs and Sinatra and I was wondering if there are any good gems for properly versioning a REST API using Sinatra. I'm using a namespace right now like this:

```
namespace '/api/v1' do
     #routes and stuff here
end
```

So if I had a version 2, I would just have to create another namespace I suppose.

Comment: You could do that, or you could do `namespace '/api/v:version' do` which would give you params[:version] and you'd be able to change behavior based on that. Either one is fine, depending on the differences between versions. The behavior is all in libraries anyway, right? :)

Comment: Take a look at the grape gem https://github.com/intridea/grape

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.ru` file, you can specify the mapping:

```
map('/v2') { run ClassNameV2 }
map('/v1') { run ClassNameV1 }
```